# Solving a non-homogenous IVP

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The question I am working on is:

**Find the solution of:**

$y'' + 4y' + 4y = 216e^{4t}$

**with** $y(0) = 4$ **and** $y'(0) = 6$

......

I assumed I would have to get it into a general form, along the lines of

$y(t) = c_1e^{-2t} + c_2te^{-2t}$

r = -2, and -2, so I put them in the complementary solution. From there I expect I would take the derivative of y(t) and then use the initial conditions to find c1, and then c2.

The extra 't' is there because it's a repeated root. It's a basic IVP.

However, I'm not sure how to approach this because of the 216e^(4t), and that's what's throwing me off. Can someone point me in the right direction and tell me where to go from here? I'm sure I can do this, I think I'm missing a few steps though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this using the method of undetermined coefficients.

You know a general solution $y_h$ to the homogeneous problem

$$
y'' + 4y' + 4y = 0
$$

To find a solution to your non-homogeneous problem, you need to find a particular solution $y_p$ of your differential equation, and then write

$$
y = y_h + y_p = c_1 e^{-2t} + c_2 t e^{-2t} + y_p
$$

and then use the initial conditions to determine $c_1$ and $c_2$.

The method of undetermined coefficients (you should look up the full details) makes a guess at $y_p$, then uses the ODE to narrow things down. In particular, for this problem, you guess that $y_p = Ae^{4t}$ (based on the form of the left-hand side and the homogeneous solution; again, you should do some reading on the particulars of this process).

Then, you plug $y_p$ into the equation, and determine what $A$ needs to be in order for

$$
y_p''+ 4y_p' + 4y_p = 216 e^{4t}
$$

Then go back and solve for $c_1,c_2$.

Comment: So I did a bit of reading on this method. I found A to be 6. So a particular solution is $y_p(t) = 6e^{4t}$ from there I just tack it on the the complementary solution and use the initial conditions to solve yes?

Comment: So after working through it, I got $y(t)= -2e^{-2t} - 12te^{-2t} + 6e^{4t}$. it says that's wrong. Any ideas why that could be wrong?

Comment: Whoops, that -12 should be a -4. Sorry! It's still wrong though

Comment: I come up with the same $A$ and $c_1$, but $c_2 = -22$. Go back to the steps to determine $c_2$ (carefully differentiate, then plug in $t = 0$) and check your work.

Comment: Found my mistake. Misread one of my numbers and it was wrong from there. Thanks for your help! I really appreciate it. Your answer is indeed correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **method of undetermined coefficients**. Assume $Y=Ae^{4t}$ solves the nonhomogeneous equation. Take its derivatives, plug into the ODE, and solve for $A$. Then your general solution is
$$y=c_1 e^{-2t}+c_2 t e^{-2t}+Ae^{4t}.$$
Now you solve for $c_1$ and $c_2$ using the initial conditions.

Note that it's really important that you solve for $A$, the unknown coefficient, **before** solving the the $c$'s using the initial conditions.

Comment: So after working through it, i got $y(t) = -2e^{-2t}  -4e^{-2t} + 6e^{4t}$. It says that's wrong. Any ideas where I could have gone wrong?

Comment: Check your initial conditions again. $y'(0)$ is not $6$ in your solution

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$
(e^{2t}y)''=e^{2t}(y''+4y'+4y).
$$